# Passing a SAFEARRAY of bytes to load function of MSXML

Tags: c++, xml, windows, msxml, safearray

If any kind soul out there please go through following source and tell me why MSXML "load" function fails to load this XML.

Here i'm trying to load a UTF-8 encoded XML using MSXML parser's "load" function. And i have a BSTR [UTF-16 encoded] as an argument, so i'm trying to convert it, into a SAFEARRAY of bytes so that i can passed it into the "load" function of MSXML. But the issue is load function failed to load this XML. If anyone could provide a solution to i would be really grateful.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objsafe.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <string>
#include <comutil.h>
#include <msxml2.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define STATUS_SUCCESS 0
#define STATUS_FAIL -1

long LoadXmlData(BSTR xmlDoc)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CComPtr <IXMLDOMDocument> xmlDomDoc = NULL;
CComPtr <IXMLDOMElement> docRoot = NULL;
VARIANT_BOOL isParseSucess = FALSE;

CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = xmlDomDoc.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return STATUS_FAIL;
}

BYTE HUGEP *pByte;
int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, xmlDoc, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
rgsabound[0].cElements = len;
rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;

SAFEARRAY* psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, rgsabound);
if (psa != NULL)
{
    hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (void HUGEP**)&pByte);
    if (!FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (len > 0)
        {
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, xmlDoc, -1, (LPSTR)&pByte[0], len, NULL, NULL);
            //cout << "Converted Byte Array: " << pByte << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            return STATUS_FAIL;
        }
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);
    }
}

VARIANT v;
VariantInit(&v);
V_VT(&v) = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;
V_ARRAY(&v) = psa;

hr = xmlDomDoc->load(v, &isParseSucess);
//hr = xmlDomDoc->loadXML(xmlDoc, &isParseSucess); //can't use this function because XML is encoded in UTF-8

if (FAILED(hr) || (!isParseSucess))
{
    return STATUS_FAIL;
}
else
{
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
}

int main()
{
BSTR xmlDoc = SysAllocString(L"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <response> </response> ");
long ret = LoadXmlData(xmlDoc);
if (ret == STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "MSXML: loading the XML succeeded";
}
else
{
    cout << "MSXML: loading the XML failed";
}
//string str;
//getline(cin, str);
return 0;
}
```

ps: If anyone try to compile this source you may get a link error first time, add comsuppw.lib as a linker dependency in VS settings. And XML is UTF-8 encoded, so i can't use "LoadXML" function in MSXML.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code. 1) you *must* use `loadXml`, there is no other possibility. 2) It's not because you put "utf-8" in the text stream that it's utf-8. Your xmlDoc BSTR defined like this is in fact unicode (so you *can* use that directly in loadXml). 3) so where is your original UTF-8 string? how is it defined technically? byte array input, other?

Answer (score 1):

XML files are UTF-8 but there is no conversion needed here because Windows functions will automatically convert between UTF-16 and UTF-8 when needed (unless input/output is `BYTE*`...)

`BSTR` needs cleanup. You can use `CComBSTR(str)` which has automatic cleanup.

You can use `const wchar_t*` to pass strings to your own functions. `BSTR` is required for COM etc.

As noted in comments, `IXMLDOMDocument::load` expects a file name as input. Use `IXMLDOMDocument::loadXML` in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <msxml2.h>

long LoadXmlData(const wchar_t* content)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMDocument> doc = NULL;
    CComPtr<IXMLDOMElement> docRoot = NULL;

    hr = doc.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument30));
    if(FAILED(hr))
        return S_FALSE;

    VARIANT_BOOL is_success = FALSE;
    CComBSTR arg(content);
    hr = doc->loadXML(arg, &is_success);

    //if you are loading from a file:
    //hr = doc->load(CComVariant(L"c:\\test\\test.xml"), &is_success);

    if(FAILED(hr) || !is_success)
        return S_FALSE;

    //if save is needed:
    //doc->save(CComVariant(L"c:\\test\\test.xml"));
    return S_OK;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    //ελληνική γλώσσα Greek text for testing
    CComBSTR data(L"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><response>ελληνική γλώσσα</response>");
    long ret = LoadXmlData(data);
    if(ret == S_OK)
        std::cout << "MSXML: loading the XML succeeded\n";
    else
        std::cout << "MSXML: loading the XML failed\n";

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```